# How do I know if Varnish cache is working on my WordPress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a WordPress website installed on my Cloudways managed server. Cloudways offer Varnish cache and I have that enabled from the server side.

In my WordPress website, I have installed a plugin called WP Fastest Cache plugin, and entered the IP address to connect to Varnish Cache.
My WordPress website is also connected to Cloudflare CDN.

So considering the above situation, how do I verify whether Varnish cache is properly linked and working on my WordPress website?

**Note:** I tried to look at the headers of the files in the website, and it appears that they only show Cloudflare info (like HIT status, cache expiry time, etc). I can't find the Varnish info. Maybe I am doing something wrong, or do I need to disconnect the website from Cloudflare CDN?

Answer (score 0):

You may have specific header with the HTTP response:

```
curl -v -o /dev/null https://yourwordpresswebsite.com/content
```

You should probably see something like

```
< x-cache: HIT
```

(or MISS if you're doing the 1st request on the content)